# cannot run gazebo9 on docker with privileged on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, x11, amd-gpu

I am stuck on this for quite a while now i have tried searching and trying stuff but i am getting nowhere.
My setup is as follows:

#### Host

linux Distro:  Archlinux
kernel version: 5.14.2
docker version: 20.10.8, build 3967b7d28e
nvidia driver version: 470.63.01-1
nvidia container toolkit version: 1.5.0-2 , cgroups disabled.
amd gpu driver: xf86-video-amdgpu 21.0.0-1

#### Container

base image: ubuntu:18.04
command line : `docker run -it --rm --privileged --gpus all -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -e XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority --network host --volume /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix --volume $XAUTHORITY:/root/.Xauthority gazebo:libgazebo9-bionic gazebo`

#### Expected results

expected gazebo window to open with hardware acceleration, using privileged access.

#### Actual results

On using `--privileged`:

```
si_init_perfcounters: max_sh_per_se = 2 not supported (inaccurate performance counters)
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 ()
  Minor opcode of failed request:  2
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

Without `--privileged` and specifying graphic cards in `--device`  manually:
gazebo window opens up with hardware acceleration and works smoothly as expected.

#### Detailed description

I was actually trying to run gazebo version 9 in a custom image which i had created using `ubuntu:18.04` as base image.  i referred to `gazebo:libgazebo9-bionic`,`nvidia/cuda:11.4.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04` and `ros:melodic-desktop` while writing the dockerfile.  i even tried the same thing for gazebo 11 on  the same base image and got the same issue as above. Whereas the exactly similar setup for ubuntu foxy works smoothly. i really need to use privileged because i am going to be working on hardware for a lot of time. please help me on how should this be fixed. thanks alot

P.S. Other GUI applications (rviz,moveit,etc)  are running without any issues. Im getting this issue with gazebo only.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with #amd-gpu?

Comment: @AlexeyR. i am using amd gpu to render

Comment: If you're disabling host networking, using the host display, and running a privileged container, are you actually getting much isolation from Docker?  Would it be easier to run this package directly on the host?

Comment: setting up ros on arch linux is a real pain @DavidMaze. thats the reason for me to use docker so i can setup a kind of virtual environment for ros.

Comment: I am facing the same error with the same configuration. Did you find any solution for this? It seems there are some solutions available for NVIDIA GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution!

Gazebo was working on `osrf/ros:noetic-desktop-full` but not on `osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full`.

I got the exact same error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 ()
```

The solution was to update the MESA drivers on the ros:melodic image from version Mesa 20.0.8 to Mesa 22.0.2.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

If you want to check your current Mesa version:

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
glxinfo | grep Mesa
```